# Docker container, starting Nodejs Server

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

i start my NodeJs server on a container. but i cant access to this server in my browser

the server starts on `localhost:8585` but when i try to access it on my browser, i receive `GET http://localhost:8585/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

what is wrong with this?

this is my server.js file

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    config = require('./config.js');

var app = new express();

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
  });

  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      console.log('!!!!!!!!-------_!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
  })

function start() {
 app.listen(config.port, function () {
    console.log('myProject listening on port ' + config.port + '!');
  });
}

exports.start = start;
```

running image with

> docker run -it -v somewhere:somewhere -p 8585:8585 --name test dockerImage

Comment: please update your question adding how you run your docker container and the dockerfile you used

Comment: Please post your docker file and also the main server file that you use for starting the server

Comment: We are not interested in the express code itself, but the Docker file and how do you run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server starts inside the container and is isolated from the rest of the world. You most probably need to expose the port `8585` from inside your container to the outside world. You can do this via the [`p` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p-expose) to `docker run` like so:

```
docker run -p localhost:8555:8585
```

You also need to [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) that port in the Dockerfile.

Comment: the problem was related to ports i used, the server port and container port should be the same, thanks for help

Comment: @Saeed.At they can also be different. So you can have the same port inside the container, but a different one outside depending on where the container is run, what other ports are in use etc. You can use `docker run -p localhost:8585:10000` to expose internal port `8585` as `10000` externally.